# Vim whole word search "pattern not found"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been trying to do a whole word search in VS Code's Vim extension. The cursor is at the top of the file, and I try looking for the word "category" with `/\<category\>`. I've also tried `/\v<category>` but that doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is type /category, I don't think there is a need for '<' or '>'.

Comment: But then how do I do a whole word search? /category will only do partial matches which often produces too many results.

Comment: so basically after some of my personal trials, looks like the vs code extension doesn't support whole word search in this approach for some reason, however, you can put the cursor on the word you want to find, and then press (SHIFT, 8) or the (*) key and it will find the next occurrence, and press (shift, 3) or the (#) key, for previous occurrence.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I knew about the * option, but it's a shame there's no way to just search for a word. Really strange that it can't be done, I appreciate you trying to figure it out though.

Answer (score 0):

The `/\<category\>` option does work for me in vscode so it must have been fixed. Hopefully your issue is gone

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30302016)